# Placing icon and title into the Button - XAML - I guess I need better approach

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styling

I'm creating button which should contain **icon/image and text** like description what's that button doing acctualy.

For example button for adding new customers might look like this, and that is how acctualy looks right now in my application:

[image]

As you can see guys, I placed icon and text "New" in this button, and this button will be used to open new window which will contain controls to insert new customer into database.

Here is my code:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnAddNewCustomer"
                Grid.Column="0"
                FontSize="15"
                BorderThickness="1.5"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="White"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
               <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>              
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="/MyProject.Wpf;component/Icons/customer-icon.png" Margin="10" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >New</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            </Button>
```

It is possible to notice, to achieve this I placed `Grid` with 2 columns in my `Button`, first column is holding image, second column is holding text **"New"**.

To me personally, it looks like this is a bad solution, I believe there is a better solution to do this, but at this moment I don't know any!

Because right now I'm learning WPF I don't wan't to go wrong way, so  guys, any suggestion will be very welcome!!

Thanks!
Cheers

Comment: You could use a stack panel, with horizontal orientation.

Comment: If it were me, I would make a custom style template for `Button` so you're not repeating all that stuff on every instance and could have some custom UX for events like MouseOver etc. Except this is more of a peer Code Review question for better practices than a single answer type question.